# send data to server continuously (By Using Rest Service) from Android service

Tags: android, web-services, rest, service

I required to send custom object to server periodically via REST API.i know there are various way available like Bound service,Job scheduler can anyone any guide or example on how to make REST API call from Android's Service or from Job scheduler Periodically furthermore How to handle scenario when service get killed by android then how to restart it for sending data.Any help will be more helpful for Novices like me.

Comment: So you know how to send data to the server? And you only have problems scheduling it or to do it periodically?

Comment: @greenapps i previously used volley so i know how to send data but in order to send periodically from background i have to use service so i don't know how to make api call from there.

Comment: Just in the same way. Why would there be any difference?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to take a look at :https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html Firebase job dispatcher you can schedule your task as your requirement and take a look at this example:https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-

Comment: what minimum interval that firebase job dispatcher supports